# SignalFx: Report a rescued exception in Ruby code, similar to NewRelic::Agent.notice_error?

Tags: ruby, exception, opentracing, signalfx

In a Ruby on Rails app, I rescue an exception in a known scenario. In the rescue, my code does a little clean up then moves on without re-raising the exception.

I want to log details of the exception to SignalFx. I believe this happens automatically if the exception is not rescued. But in this case I need to rescue it.

We are currently migrating from New Relic to SignalFx. In New Relic, I could force the rescued exception to be logged like this:

```
rescue MySpecialError => ex
  NewRelic::Agent.notice_error ex
  record.clean_up_after_my_special_error()
```

This would record the stack trace, request params, env vars, etc, exactly as if the exception was not rescued.

Is there a similar way with SignalFx to capture rich exception information without raising the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://github.com/signalfx/signalfx-ruby#sending-events),

```
client = SignalFx.new 'MY_SIGNALFX_TOKEN'
client.send_event('EXCEPTION', ... )
```

You may want to consider using a more focused error-reporting service.

Comment: Thanks, @Josh Brody, I'll give that a try. I'm curious, why do you recommend that? I've got all of one day's experience with SignalFx. My company decided to make the move, so I know little about the why behind it.